# can i force vim to exit with 0 status

Tags: vim

I'm running the default vim on OSX. (sierra, if it matters).  If I search for a non-existent string at any time during my session, vim exits with a non-zero exit code.  Normally I don't care, but with svn commits or resolving conflicts this is a problem.  I know :cq forces vim to exit with an error.  Is there the opposite function?  Some command that forces vim to exit with a status of 0?

Comment: What is the status of your filetype in your vimrc?

Comment: That's not how `vim` usually behaves.  What version of `vim` are you using? How did you install it?

Comment: How about looking for the cause instead of working around the effect? Does it happen with `$ vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: The first 2 lines of my .vimrc are:
filetype on
filetype off.

I'm using the /usr/bin/vim that comes with OSX Sierra.

The cause is searching for a non-existent string, which I could see might be wanted in a script.  But I'm interactively editing a file and if I forget and search for a string and then :wq, my commit message or conflict resolution fails.

Comment: And by the way - I don't have this problem on another linux system I use.  Only on my mac.

Comment: I asked a specific thing, can you give an actual answer?

Comment: We're all telling you this is not how Vim normally behaves. I just tested it on my Mac: `/usr/bin/vim -Nu NONE && echo foo` will output `foo` even if I do a failing search. So will `vim && echo foo`, meaning I haven't broken it with any of my customisations. It will fail to print `foo` if I exit using `:cq`. Executing romainl's test is important so we can eliminate whether the issue is due to plugins, or weird Vim build.

Comment: Also, make sure you are running `vim`, not `vi` (where I do replicate your behaviour on my Mac).

Comment: ok, this may be a more complicated interaction between svn and vim, but i don't understand how.  i just did this:  setenv EDITOR '/usr/bin/vim -Nu NONE' and did an svn commit.  i typed in my commit message, then searched for a string that wasn't there (which in long commit messages i sometimes do), then did :wq and svn rejected the commit.  part of the message said this:  "system('vi svn-commit.2.tmp') returned 256" .   does that mean svn is ignoring my EDITOR setting?  if so, i apologize.  i'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: i just retried my commit with 'svn commit --editor-cmd '/usr/bin/vim'  myfile' and it worked perfectly.   so svn is my problem and vim is blameless.  this has been a pain for me for more than a year.  thanks for the help and sorry for blaming vim!

Answer (score 2):

Vim was always doing the right thing - it was correctly exiting with a 0 error code.  My actual problem turned out to be that subversion (svn) was not honoring the EDITOR environment variable, as documented.  It was actually using 'vi' and it was returning the bad exit code.  Setting SVN_EDITOR to vim fixed my longstanding problem with commits and conflict resolution.

Comment: This put to rest a very similar long-standing issue for me. My EDITOR was set to `vi` and not `vim` and git was behaving as svn was for you. Thanks!