# How can I force vi/vim to exit cleanly with status 0

Tags: vim

When editing with `vim`, the normal exit code is 0. For example:

```sh
vi; echo $?
```

will return `0` if you just do `:q` immediately. However, it will return `1` (or other error codes) if you **ever** enter a bad command. For example, typing `:aaa` in `vim` will give the error `E492: Not an editor command: aaa` in vim. After that point, no matter what I do, `vim` will subsequently exit with status 1.

This is a problem when editing `git` commit messages, because if you ever make a mistake while typing (easy to do in `vim`), the subsequent commit message will be thrown away. (Yes, I know there are ways to retrieve it - I don't want that hassle every time I know I made a mistake.)

**The question**: is there a `vim` command to "reset" the exit code to 0?

There is a similar question here: [can i force vim to exit with 0 status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087047/can-i-force-vim-to-exit-with-0-status). However, that one is due to using `vi` instead of `vim`, which (apparently) exits with non-zero if you search for a non-existent string. This question is specifically about `vim`.

**Edit**: Thanks for the answers here! Some additional details:

- this is on MacOS 11.2.1.
- I have no `~/.vimrc` so I'm just falling back to the Mac-provided `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`, which seems pretty basic.
- calling `vi -u NONE` still causes the behavior described above.
- (*most interesting*) calling `vim` fixes the problem. Yes, I know I mentioned above that the other answer was using `vi` instead of `vim`, but I was thrown off by this:

```sh
$ which vi
/usr/bin/vi
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
$ ls -l /usr/bin/vi
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel        3 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/vi -> vim
```

And when I run either `vi --version` or `vim --version`, I get *identically* the same output. Does `vim` change its behavior depending on the calling executable name? And if so, is there something I can stick in my `.vimrc` to override whatever that switch is? I'd love to know. In the meantime, I can fix this with `export EDITOR="vim"`.

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Ran `vim; echo $?`, entered `:aaa`, got an error, entered `:q`, exited, got `0` as the error code. Could be something in your `.vimrc` or plugins. Start debugging with `vim -u NONE`

Comment: You could try the `:0cq` command suggested in a deleted answer on that same post. However, like @phd, I can't reproduce the problem. Note that I use `ZZ` to exit vim, which is equivalent to `:x`: it only writes to the file if there are changes. It then exits if it didn't write (nothing to write) or the write was successful. This differs from :wq which writes, then exits whether or not the write was successful. (In both cases "quitting" "fails", i.e., the editor sticks around, if there are more files to edit; a second attempt to quit will actually quit.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Vim (and at least some other implementations of vi, such as nvi), return 0 if a "normal" error occurs, such as an invalid command or another normal user input error.  It *is* the behavior of ed to exit nonzero in such a case, and as you've found, that behavior is generally undesirable because humans are imperfect and make many mistakes, which is why Vim doesn't do that.

Vim should exit nonzero if you use `:cq`, which has this behavior intentionally, as well as if certain error conditions are met (e.g., you run `vim -y` but the display cannot be started.

It is possible you have a configuration setting or plugin that causes this behavior.  You can try running with `vim -u NONE -U NONE` to verify this, and then isolate the problem by commenting out portions of your `.vimrc`.  It is also possible that your Vim distributor thought this would be a desirable feature to add and patched it in for you, but you haven't mentioned your OS or source of Vim packages, so it's hard to say.

To always force a zero exit, you can try `:cq 0`, but that is no more likely to work than a standard `:q`, since they both call the exact same function (`getout`) with the exact same value (0).

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing this behavior as well on macOS 11.6, and it only happens when invoked as `vi` – not `vim`.

#### Why does this happen?

If we look at `vim --version`:

```
> vim --version                                                                                                                                                 
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Aug 30 2021 06:51:40)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-2029
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

The *macOS version* here let's us know that something might be up.

Looking at vim's `main.c` in the Apple's open source repository (https://opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-91/src/main.c.auto.html), we find this inside the `int main()` function:

```c
Unix2003_compat = 0;
if (strcmp(base,"vi")==0) {
    Unix2003_compat = COMPAT_MODE("bin/vi", "Unix2003");
} else if (strcmp(base,"ex")==0) {
    Unix2003_compat = COMPAT_MODE("bin/ex", "Unix2003");
}
```

and then in `void getout(int exitval)`:

```c
if (exmode_active || Unix2003_compat )
    exitval += ex_exitval;
```

The `Unix2003_compat` parts here are not present in [the official Vim sources](https://github.com/vim/vim).

So on the macOS version of vim, if invoked as `vi` or `ex` you'll get this error preserving behavior.

**Note:** The Apple URL is confusing – `vim-91` really corresponds to vim 8.2, which can be checked by looking at `version.h` in the same repo.

#### Solution

Invoke vim as `vim` instead of as `vi`. In the case of `git` set the `EDITOR` environment variable to `vim` in your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`config.fish`.

Alternately, install the official vim through something like Homebrew.

Comment: Awesome answer - that finally answers my question about why the behavior differs depending on the basename of the executable. Nice!

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled upon this behavior myself and didn't find a proper answer here – so I started digging :) Annoying that your question has been downvoted (was -1 before I voted) when it's quite an annoyance for macOS users and interesting at the same time.